# Is it possible to change the result of a syntax-class?

Tags: racket

I currently have a bunch of splicing syntax classes I use to generate code.
They look like this:

```lisp
(define-splicing-syntax-class vec-exp
  (pattern (~seq x y)
    #:with result #'(vec x y)))
```

The goal is to be able to match a sequence `x y` anywhere and replace it with `(vec x y)`.

The only way I see for now is by creating an attribute called `result` and use it:

```lisp
> (syntax-parse #'(position 4.2 5.7)
    [(<name> <pos>:vec-exp)
     (attribute <pos>.result)])
#'(vec 4.2 5.7)
```

Is there a way to change my code so that I can get the same result by writing the following?

```lisp
> (syntax-parse #'(position 4.2 5.7)
    [(<name> <pos>:vec-exp)
     (attribute <pos>)])
#'(4.2 5.7) ;; not what I want
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, you can do this. Not sure if it's acceptable for you or not.

```
(require syntax/parse
         (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-splicing-syntax-class vec-exp
  (pattern (~seq x y) #:with result #'(vec x y)))

(define-syntax ~res
  (pattern-expander
   (syntax-parser
     [(_ pat cls)
      #'(~and (~var PAT cls) (~bind [pat (attribute PAT.result)]))])))
```

And then:

```
> (syntax-parse #'(position 4.2 5.7)
    [(<name> (~res <pos> vec-exp))
     (attribute <pos>)])
#'(vec 4.2 5.7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The pattern `(<name> <pos>:vec-exp)` means "The input must be a list; bind its elements to pattern variables `<name>` and `<pos>`." Those pattern variables provide access to *what got matched.* The attributes returned by the syntax class are *what got generated.* The `syntax-parse` system is very fastidious about keeping those two concepts distinct, so I don't think it will let you replace one with the other.

Are you trying to make your macro more readable or less error-prone? If so, maybe tell us a little more. Maybe there is a way to do that.